# imprimir texto sem regra de translineação

Tags: python

preciso imprimir  um texto de um arquivo em uma unica linha sem os traços de quebra de linha.

```
def imprime_texto():
with open("texto.txt") as arquivo:
    linhas = arquivo.read().split("\n")
for linha in linhas:
    print(linha.strip(), end=" ")
```

Entrada:

```
  Programar em python é mui-
  to simples é só praticar.
```

Saida correta : sem o traço.

```
  Programar em python é muito simples é só praticar.
```

Minha saida está com o traço em mui-to e no final sai o None 
não sei onde estou errando no código.

```
  Programar em python é mui- to simples é só praticar. None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para remover o `-`

ou remove ele da entrada

```
Programar em python é mui 
to simples é só praticar.
```

ou é possível utilizar o `replace`

```
for linha in linhas:
    linha = linha.replace("-", "")
    print(linha.strip(), end=" ")
```

<sub>obs: utilizar o `replace` pode ser ruim, pois irá remover qualquer entrada que tenha `-`, ex: **pré-história** ficará **préhistória**</sub>

Já para remover o espaço em branco que está ficando após o `-`, basta alterar seu `end` para

```
print(linha.strip(), end="")
```

segue como ficou o código:

```
def imprime_texto():
    with open("C:\\Shared\\teste.txt") as arquivo:
        linhas = arquivo.read().split("\n")
    for linha in linhas:
        linha = linha.replace("-", "")
        print(linha.strip(), end="")
imprime_texto()
```

Saída:

> Programar em python é muito simples é só praticar.

**EDIT**

Conforme comentado pelo [Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5749/miguel)
há outra solução, que é bem melhor e com menos código que a solução acima, seria fazer todo processo na leitura do arquivo.

```
def imprime_texto():
    with open("C:\\caminho\\teste.txt") as arquivo:
        linhas = arquivo.read().replace("-\n", "").replace('\n', "")
        print(linhas)        
imprime_texto()
```

**EDIT 2**

Temos outra solução!!!

Agora comentada pelo [Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/82711/isac)

> "Outra solução interessante para remover o `-` é fazer `strip("-")` que
>   também garante que apenas apanha os que estão no fim de cada linha "

```
def imprime_texto():
    with open("C:\\caminho\\teste.txt") as arquivo:
        linhas = arquivo.read().split("\n")
    for linha in linhas:
        linha = linha.strip("-")
        print(linha.strip(), end="")
imprime_texto()
```

Comment: Obgado, não precisava de dar o mérito. Ainda bem que ajudei+1

Comment: Obrigado amigos, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @Miguel méritos sempre  ;)

Comment: @Bruno não esqueça de marcar como respondida https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Ok Barbetta pode deixar amigo.

Comment: Outra solução interessante para remover o `-` é fazer `strip("-")` que também garante que apenas apanha os que estão no fim de cada linha